# How to modify the default ip address of huawei usb modem e3531i-2

Tags: modem, huawei-developers, 3g, dongle

want to change the default lan ip address from "192.168.8.1" to something else of device huawei usb modem e3531i-2 (HiLink), cause if i plug two of the modems there will be ip conflict and the latter will block the first modem, thanks.
["usb stick model"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NEIs.png) -
["hilink web app"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRxl4.png)

i want to plug multiple huawei modems e3531i-2 in a single pc without getting ip conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Found the solution !

my os is ubuntu 22.04 LTS, modem huawei e3531i-2, but i hope it can works for other modems.

- first list your connected usb using command `lsusb | grep Huawei` it should look like this:  `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.`
- The 12d1:1f01 indicates that the modem is in storage mode and we need to switch it to serial mode. type `sudo nano /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1f01`
- Once the file is created now copy paste the text below inside and save :

```
# Huawei E3531
DisableSwitching=1
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProduct=0x1001
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
NoDriverLoading=1
```

- re-plug your modem again and now if you type `lsusb | grep Huawei` it should look like this : `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co.,`, If the modem doesn’t switch into 12d1:1001 mode, try rerunning the above command with -I.
- now you're able to run AT commands using `screen /dev/ttyUSB0` or controlling it using modemmanager "i would recommend not using the GUI but instead use mmcli"